How can I override or extend javascript await to add extra behaviour?
Every time I use await in my code, I want a loading screen to appear. It's getting tiresome having to always write:
this.startLoading();
await fetch(//do something);
this.stopLoading();

or
this.startLoading();
await lastValueFrom(this.http.get<Array<MiningRigDevice>>('/mining/devices')).then(res => this.miningRigDevices = res);
this.stopLoading();

How can I override the behavior of await to something like
loadingDivOn() 
await(some operation) 
loadingDivOff()

Note this has to handle any type of operation after await, not just fetch.

You know SO isn't for getting people's opinions or getting recommendations. Come up with some solutions, try them, and if you get stuck, that might be the right time to ask here? Creating an async function that you wrap your real calls in, and that you use wherever you need a loading screen (because you guaranteed don't want one for every single instance of await) shouldn't take more than a few minutes.

great, the question is to show what kind of function could come close to what i want - i have no solution

Does this answer your question? Override fetch method in JS and forward Promises

no because its not only fetch, but anything after await. in my example i also have this.http.delete

Ok, not included in your question but what stops you from creating an async function that can accept async function as an argument? Which will show and hide loaders? like await withLoader(async () => {... await fetch(...);  await this.http.delete()})?

Create a function that accepts a promise runner (ie a function that returns a promise of your desired task) as parameter.
Inside this function, first execute what is supposed to happen before you execute your async task. After that return await run() will create your desired promise, await it and return its result. And finally, execute what is supposed to happen after your async task.


let throwError = false;

let fetchRunner = async () => {
  console.log("in runner");
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000));
  console.log("after timeout");
  return fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products");
}

let fetchRunnerError = async () => {
  console.log("in runner");
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000));
  console.log("after timeout");
  return fetch("https://example.com/products");
}


let withLoadingScreen = async (runner) => {
  try {
    //startLoading();
    console.log("loading on");
    if (throwError) throw new Error("loading on error");
    return await runner();
  } finally {
    //stopLoading();
    console.log("loading off")
  }
}

async function main() {
  console.log("running without error");
  await withLoadingScreen(fetchRunner)
    .then(response => console.log(response.status))
      .catch(e => console.log(e.message))
    .then(() => console.log("finished"))
 

  console.log("\n\nrunning with fetch error");
  await withLoadingScreen(fetchRunnerError)
    .then(response => console.log(response.status))
      .catch(e => console.log(e.message))
    .then(() => console.log("finished"))  
    
  console.log("\n\nrunning with error of loading screen");
  throwError = true;
  await withLoadingScreen(fetchRunner)
    .then(response => console.log(response.status))
      .catch(e => console.log(e.message))
    .then(() => console.log("finished"))  
    
}

main();



By using try ... finally it's guaranteed that this.stopLoading() will always be called, regardless of whether your promise resolves or rejects. But not having a catch block in the promiseWrapper will  pass on any exception thrown by the promise (or by startLoading() and stopLoading() respecitvely if they can throw).
Passing a function instead of a promise (thanks for that comment @Bergi) has the advantage, you only call for instance fetch once startLoading() succeeded. But be aware of the issues with arrow functions and this ...
The snippet shows three scenarios

a successful request
an unsuccessful request
an error with your loading screen


It would be slightly cleaner to pass a run callback, not a promise. If loadingDivOn() fails for some reason (i.e. throws an exception), you wouldn't want to call run().

what does passing a run callback mean? can we please vote to reopen this question, this function is great but it fails when you need to handle something like :
await lastValueFrom(this.http.get<Array>('/mining/devices')).then(res => this.miningRigDevices = res);

@MaxAlexanderHanna "fails" in what sense?

@Bergi you are absolutely right. Adapted the answer
